# In emacs "M-q" does not work?

Tags: emacs, emacs23

I'm using GNU Emacs 23.3.1. When I press "M-q" emacs says "M-q is undefined". How can I solve this issue? Thanks.

Comment: `M-q` is normally bound to `fill-paragraph`. Does this happen if you start Emacs without your own init file. In that case you can try to find the culprit by using more and more if it.

Comment: @Lindydancer: it doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start Emacs with the `-Q` option, and see if the problem persists by typing <kbd>C-h k M-q</kbd>. If it turns out that <kbd>M-q</kbd> is in fact bound to `fill-paragraph` that way, then something in your init file apparently undoes that key binding.

You could then comment out some of your customizations in the .emacs file in a "binary search" style to find which one of them is responsible for removing said key binding.

Comment: emacs says "M-q runs the command fill-paragraph, which is an interactive compiled Lisp function in `fill.el'.
It is bound to M-q.
(fill-paragraph &optional JUSTIFY REGION) etc....". But still it does not work. Even after I removed my .emacs file.

Comment: @beegii: Just curious, what caused the problem?

Comment: @Lindydancer Hey, I just realized that you pretty much already gave the same answer in your very first comment to the OP's question. I think it's unfair that I'm getting the credit for it, so why don't you put it as an answer so beegii can tick it as the correct one?

Comment: @Thomas: Thanks, but as an old-time Emacs user, I'm just glad that the problem was solved. You can enjoy the rep:s without any regrets...

Comment: @Lindydancer Cheers, mate, then I will sit back now and enjoy the credit... :-)

Comment: @Lindydancer: I followed Thomas's guide. So I did a binary search on my .emacs. The problem was on the following four rows: (global-set-key (read-kbd-macro "ESC ") 'my-next-buffer) 
(global-set-key (read-kbd-macro "ESC ") 'my-prev-buffer)
(global-set-key (read-kbd-macro "ESC ") 'windmove-up)
(global-set-key (read-kbd-macro "ESC ") 'windmove-down). And I just deleted them and it worked out :). I don't know why they cause the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Place this line in your .emacs file and restart emacs.

```
(global-set-key "\M-q" 'fill-paragraph)
```